# If $T\colon X \to Y$ is a nonlinear compact operator, is it bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T\colon X \to Y$ is a nonlinear compact operator between reflexive Banach spaces, does it take bounded sets into bounded sets?

It is definitely true in the linear case but I guess it's not true for the nonlinear case.

Comment: How do you define compactness of a nonlinear mapping?

Comment: @gerw If it's continuous and it takes a bounded set into a relatively compact set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Relatively compact sets are bounded.